# UICollectionView's weird snapping

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to programmatically scroll to a specific index in a UICollectionView from another UICollectionView, but the scroll is not happening.

I need help figuring out what is causing the scrolling not to occur and how to fix it. I have already confirmed that the code to trigger the scroll is being called and that the correct index is being passed in. I also checked that the contentOffset values are not changing after the attempted scroll.
I need assistance in identifying potential reasons why the scrolling is not working and how to resolve them. Thank You

**UPDATE**

I have fixed it by setting isPagingEnabled to true and false but now it has this weird snapping effect like shown in the video below

[image]

```swift
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, MenuControllerDelegate {
    
    func didTapMenuItem(index: Int) {
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false
        collectionView.scrollToItem(
            at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0),
            at: .centeredHorizontally,
            animated: true
        )
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    }
    
    fileprivate let menuController = MenuController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
        menuController.delegate = self
        menuController.collectionView.selectItem(at: [0,0], animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
        
        if let layout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
         
        }
        
        setupLayout()
        
        collectionView.register(MainCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "main")
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.allowsSelection = true
    }
    fileprivate func setupLayout(){
        view.addSubview(menuController.view)
        
        menuController.view.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: nil, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: 0, height: 70))
        
        collectionView.anchor(top: menuController.view.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    }
    
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let offset = x / 2
        menuController.menuBar.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: offset, y: 0)
    }

    override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        let x = targetContentOffset.pointee.x
        let item = x / view.frame.width
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: Int(item), section: 0)
        menuController.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "main", for: indexPath) as! MainCell
        
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            cell.backgroundColor = .blue
        }else if indexPath.item == 1 {
            cell.backgroundColor = .green
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let height = view.frame.height
        let width = view.frame.width
        return .init(width: width, height: height - 70)
    }
}
```

```swift
protocol MenuControllerDelegate {
    
    func didTapMenuItem(index: Int)
}
```

```swift
class MenuController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    fileprivate let menuItems = ["Today", "News"]
    
    var delegate: MenuControllerDelegate?
    
    let menuBar: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 35
       return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        collectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 35
        
        collectionView.register(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        if let layout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        }
        
        
        view.addSubview(menuBar)
        menuBar.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, trailing: nil, size: .init(width: 0, height: 70))
        menuBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/2).isActive = true
 
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let x = view.frame.width / 2 * CGFloat(indexPath.item)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0,usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            
            self.menuBar.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: x, y: 0)
        })
        delegate?.didTapMenuItem(index: indexPath.item)
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return menuItems.count
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MenuCell
        cell.label.text = menuItems[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        let width = view.frame.width
        return .init(width: width / 2, height: view.frame.height)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"weird snapping effect"* is happening because you are transforming the view twice...

In `MenuController`:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let x = view.frame.width / 2 * CGFloat(indexPath.item)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0,usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        // animate the transform
        self.menuBar.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: x, y: 0)

    })

    // this is called immediately (i.e. it doesn't wait for the animation)
    delegate?.didTapMenuItem(index: indexPath.item)
}
```

Then in that delegate func in `CollectionViewController`:

```
func didTapMenuItem(index: Int) {
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false

    // this will trigger scrollViewDidScroll
    collectionView.scrollToItem(
        at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0),
        at: .centeredHorizontally,
        animated: true
    )

    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
}
```

so while the collection view is scrolling due to calling `.scrollToItem`, this will be called many times:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let offset = x / 2

    // set a new transform
    menuController.menuBar.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: offset, y: 0)
}
```

To fix the weird snapping, change your `didSelectItemAt` to this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // this is all that's needed
    delegate?.didTapMenuItem(index: indexPath.item)

}
```

As a side note, I don't see any difference related to your `.isPagingEnabled` toggling off/on... the animation and `scrollTo` happens just fine with those lines removed.