# ScrollViewDidScroll Offset Issues

Tags: ios, swift

The issue is when the `indicatorBackground` view is given a padding of 16 points on both sides, it is causing the `indicator` view to go beyond the visible area of the `indicatorBackground` view. The `indicator` view moves past the edge of the screen when the user scrolled to the second item in the collectionView. I think for this issue you need to adjust the `scrollViewDidScroll` function to take into account the new padding of the `indicatorBackground` view and adjust the end point of the indicator view accordingly but i have tried everything and nothing seems to be working.

[image]

***Full Code***

```swift
class CollectionPager: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, CollectionDelegate {
    
    func didTapHeaderCell(index: Int) {
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false
        collectionView.scrollToItem(
            at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0),
            at: .centeredHorizontally,
            animated: true
        )
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    }

    let indicator: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 26
       return v
    }()
    let indicatorBackground: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemGroupedBackground
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
       return v
    }()
    
    fileprivate let collectionHeader = CollectionHeader(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground
        collectionHeader.delegate = self
        collectionHeader.collectionView.selectItem(at: [0,0], animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
        
        if let layout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
         
        }
        
        setupLayout()
        
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.register(PagerCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PagerCell")
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.allowsSelection = true
    }

    fileprivate func setupLayout(){

        view.addSubview(indicatorBackground)
        view.addSubview(indicator)
        view.addSubview(collectionHeader.view)
        
        indicatorBackground.anchor(
            top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
            leading: view.leadingAnchor,
            bottom: collectionView.topAnchor,
            trailing: view.trailingAnchor,
            padding: .init(top: 24, left: 16, bottom: 4, right: 16),
            size: .init(width: 0, height: 60)
        )
        
        indicator.anchor(
            top: indicatorBackground.topAnchor,
            leading: indicatorBackground.leadingAnchor,
            bottom: indicatorBackground.bottomAnchor,
            trailing: nil,
            padding: .init(top: 4, left: 4, bottom: 4, right: 4)
        )
        indicator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: indicatorBackground.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
        
        collectionHeader.view.anchor(
            top: indicatorBackground.topAnchor,
            leading: indicatorBackground.leadingAnchor,
            bottom: indicatorBackground.bottomAnchor,
            trailing: indicatorBackground.trailingAnchor,
            padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0),
            size: .init(width: 0, height: 60)
        )

        collectionView.anchor(
            top: indicatorBackground.bottomAnchor,
            leading: view.leadingAnchor,
            bottom: view.bottomAnchor,
            trailing: view.trailingAnchor,
            padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        )
    }
    
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let offset = x / 2
        indicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: offset, y: 0)
    }



    override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        let x = targetContentOffset.pointee.x
        print(x)
        let item = x / view.frame.width
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: Int(item), section: 0)
        collectionHeader.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
        collectionHeader.selectedIndex = indexPath.item
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PagerCell", for: indexPath) as! PagerCell
        
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            cell.label.text = "Today"
            cell.backgroundColor = .red
        }else if indexPath.item == 1 {
            cell.label.text = "News"
            cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let height = view.frame.height
        let width = view.frame.width
        return .init(width: width, height: height)
    }
}


class PagerCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let label: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.textAlignment = .center
        return l
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(label)
        label.fillSuperview()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

protocol CollectionDelegate {
    
    func didTapHeaderCell(index: Int)
}

class CollectionHeader: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    fileprivate let titles = ["Today", "News"]
    
    var delegate: CollectionDelegate?
    
    let menuBar: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
       return v
    }()
    var selectedIndex: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        
        collectionView.register(HeaderCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell")
        
        if let layout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        }
        selectedIndex = 0
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.didTapHeaderCell(index: indexPath.item)
        selectedIndex = indexPath.item
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return titles.count
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell
        cell.label.text = titles[indexPath.item]
        cell.label.textColor = indexPath.item == selectedIndex ? .black : .lightGray
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        let width = view.frame.width
        return .init(width: width / 2, height: view.frame.height)
    }
}

class HeaderCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let label: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.textAlignment = .center
        l.textColor = .lightGray
        l.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
        return l
    }()
    
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            label.textColor = isSelected ? .black : .lightGray
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(label)
        label.fillSuperview()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly this is only about the fake UISegmentedControl at the top? We can ignore the lower part of the screen and all the other code? Can you cut it all down to just the relevant code? I've written a fake segmented control and it's quite easy. But I can't find the relevant part of the code in your question.

Comment: Or might it better if you just used a _real_ UISegmentedControl?

Comment: @GILL - what is the difference between this question and the very similar one from you yesterday? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75526885/uicollectionviews-weird-snapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple tips...

**First**, double-check that the code you post will run. In this case, it won't because you're using an Extension for your constraints.

**Second**, while I know some people find constraint / anchor Extensions easier to work with, it's not always clear exactly what is going on. And, if we try to help you, we have to figure out what the Extension is doing.

So, ***particularly during development***, I highly recommend using standard constraint syntax.

**Third**, make sure the code produces the output you've shown. In this case, using your code as-is with a default `UICollectionViewController` (after finding a constraints extension that appears to match), it looks like this:

[image]

After figuring out that I needed to set `Cell -> Estimate Size: None` in Storyboard... and setting `indicatorBackground.backgroundColor = .systemBlue`... it looks like this:

[image]

So, let's check the view frames using Debug View Hierarchy:

[image]

as you can see, your white "indicator" view is too wide, because you set its constraints like this:

```
    indicator.anchor(
        top: indicatorBackground.topAnchor,
        leading: indicatorBackground.leadingAnchor,
        bottom: indicatorBackground.bottomAnchor,
        trailing: nil,
        padding: .init(top: 4, left: 4, bottom: 4, right: 4)
    )
    indicator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: indicatorBackground.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
```

Its width has been set to 50% of the `indicatorBackground` width, ***but*** you've given it 4-points of leading space ... so it is 8-points too wide.

Your constraint should be:

```
    indicator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: indicatorBackground.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
```

Now when we check it, we see this:

[image]

Let's tap "News" (or drag to scroll) and we get this:

[image]

Why is it in the wrong place? Well, this code:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let offset = x / 2
    
    indicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: offset, y: 0)
}
```

says:

- get the red/yellow scroll view's content offset x
- divide by 2
- move the indicator that much to the right

But the width of `indicatorBackground` is *narrower* than the width of the scroll view... and you `indicator` is even narrower than one-half of that width.

We need to get the **percentage** of the scroll view's offset x, and then move the `indicator` by that percentage of its "total horizontal range":

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let x: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let svW: CGFloat = scrollView.frame.width
    let pct: CGFloat = x / svW
    
    let iw: CGFloat = indicator.frame.width + 8.0
    let offset: CGFloat = iw * pct
    
    indicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: offset, y: 0)
}
```

and we (finally) get this result:

[image]

Comment: Couldnt have asked for a better answer, Thank you!